# Openscad sub-assemblies single STL file

Tags: openscad

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to make a single STL file via OpenSCAD that has named sub-assemblies. I read the STL spec (since that has been what I'm importing). I don't know even for sure that the software (xray-sim) can properly handle the subassembly.

The item I'm making has definitive materials. Each material I need to load into the simulation software and assign it to a portion of the object. A single object would let me manipulate it easier in the sim software, and assign materials as needed to the sub components.

I can't figure out how to do this, or if it is possible. Reading examples suggest concatenating ASCII STL files together, then modifying the vertex/face counts. That would be my last resort for maintainability.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

STL files do not have named sub-assemblies. Concatenating multiple STL files together will not cause STL files to have named sub-assemblies, and there's easier ways to do that than catting files together, you could use tools like meshlab or blender.

You probably need to export each "sub-assembly" as their own STL file, you can automate that through the openscad command line interface.

Beyond that your question is too unclear to answer well.

Comment: You've answered well for my poorly phrased. I read the STL spec and saw 'name' was an option, but couldn't figure out whether or not it was really supported or not. I have been using meshlab to convert ASCII to Binary STLs, as this old package only supports binary. Ideally I'd like 1 object out that has each sub-assembly iterable, but that doesn't seem to be possible.